# What is a suitable word to describe a place where two rivers meet?

Tags: single-word-requests, geography

I've googled for a while and on some sites I've found the word "watershed" as the proposed word. Is it the word that best suits it?

Comment: A *watershed* is a line where rain water is divided (i.e. will it flow into one valley to the river there, or to the other valley), so typically found atop hills.

Comment: A watershed is the area of land where water drains to a common point. A divide is the line that divides watersheds.

Comment: @JayElston While ODO gives both senses, the primary one is the dividing feature. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/watershed In my experience of UK English we would genereally use 'water catchment' for the second sense.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

In geography, a [confluence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluence) is the meeting of two or more bodies of water. It usually refers to the point where two streams flow together, merging into a single stream.

Comment: +1 Nice answer... This question also reminded me of when i used to study Geography earlier in my student career :D

Comment: Indeed it reminded of my geography classes too while at primary school...but since it's way too back...I forgot it.

Comment: I didn't seriously study any geography, but I do use Atlassian's Wiki which is named Confluence.

Comment: Flannery O'Conner wrote that "confluence" was one of her favorite words. Easy to see why - it's a strong metaphor.

Comment: @The Raven Yes it is, and onomatopoeic, to my ears at least.

Comment: @Ed Guinness - I was once at a job where we used that for the workgroup's Wiki.  In light of this geographical meaning i think its a pretty good name.  A point where all team members can cooperate/share/merge/etc

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the word ***junction***, as in the

> junction of the Grand and the Green

near Moab, Utah.

Answer (score 5):

It can either be a tributary or a distributary, where a river joins another or separate from one respectively.

It is called a confluence. A tributary is a smaller river joining a larger one. A distributary is a river flowing into the sea.

Comment: More specifically, a tributary is a small river or stream joining the main river

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the word "fork" which is less formal. A watershed is all of the land area that a given body of water drains.

Comment: Except that a fork takes one and makes two, a confluence takes two and makes one.

Answer (score -1):

It could also be an "[estuary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estuary)":

> [A] partly enclosed coastal body of
>   water with one or more rivers or
>   streams flowing into it, and with a
>   free connection to the open sea.

Comment: That's pretty far from "a place where two rivers meet", since it does not require more than one river, and does require the open sea.