# What do you call the body of water into which a river flows?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, the Nile flows into the Mediterranean. The Mediterranean is therefore the Nile's ***_*___**.

Edit: I'm looking for a way to name the Mediterranean *in relation to* the Nile. The Nile is one of the Mediterranean's *affluents*, so the Mediterranean is the Nile's ***_*___**.

Comment: Is that *Ausfluß* in German?

Comment: @GEdgar I don't believe so, as *Ausfluß* seems to designate the water flowing out, rather than the bodies of water following the target river downstream to the ocean.

Comment: I think that usage of *affluent* is at least unusual. Normally in the [fluvial](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fluvial) context, affluents are tributaries that flow into larger rivers, not large rivers that flow into seas.

Comment: ...I edited the question because I can't for the life of me see how the Mediterranean could be **one of** the Nile's *anythings*. Whatever the Med is in this context, it's the *only one* the Nile has.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Consider a river flowing into the Nile. Then both the Nile and the Mediterranean would be this rivers' __________s...

Comment: [Confluence](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/25545/5822)?

Comment: @Shawn: That doesn't make much sense given your question's title. Callithumpian's *confluence* could be stretched to mean any point where two bodies/flows of water meet, just as you stretched *affluence* to mean all flowing water. But if you want a word for your river's **X** that applies to both the Nile *and* the Med, you should edit the question to reflect that clearly. I don't think most people would be expecting this to be an obvious concept for which one might seek a word (or even phrase).

Comment: @FumbleFingers How could you talk about the series of rivers and lakes which take the outflow of one river down to the Ocean (or desert basin) without having to name every one of those rivers and lakes?

Comment: The general area covered by the "confluent" rivers is called the **[catchment] basin**. The rivers themselves are invariably the **tributaries**, but that *doesn't* include the final main one they all flow into. There seems to be no special word for the entire system including the sea it all ends up flowing into. I'd just call it an *interconnected water system*. But at the end of the day, the Atlantic and the Pacific are in fact connected, so I can't see any such word being particularly precise anyway.

Comment: ...how about a *semi-autonomous hydrological subsystem*?

Comment: what about a river's *downstream*..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[This](http://www.buzzle.com/articles/geology-terms-glossary-of-geology-terms-and-definitions.html#W) is a decent list of geological terms, and it doesn't have any word to specifically identify the relation of a river to its final outflow point (where it discharges). Which might not be into an ocean or sea - sometimes it's [a desert basin](http://www.lycos.com/info/kalahari-desert--south-africa.html?page=2).

I think *mouth* does well enough for the actual place where the river ends (assuming it doesn't just peter out in the desert), but that doesn't really embrace the whole body of water. I wouldn't object to *outlet* or *outflow* either, but I doubt they're commonly used in this exact context.

In short, I don't think there's a "real" technical term - but I'm not a geologist, so I don't know. The best I can come up with is **terminus**. For example, the Awash River drains into Lake Abbe, which is [described as its terminus](http://www.wildernesslectures.com/speaker.php?id=143). Also [the Black Sea is the terminus for a number of large rivers](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/archive/index.php/t-38420.html).

Comment: +1 I think it's terminus as well.

Comment: Ok, this is pretty old and terminus seems to be the closest to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 10):

Unless there is an arcane word for it, I would call it the river's *destination*.

Comment: I am indeed looking for a technical term, be it arcane or not.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted name for the endpoint of a river is either *mouth* if it goes right into a big body of water, [estuary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estuary) if it goes into a smaller semi-enclosed coastal body of water connected to a larger body, or *confluence* if it goes into another river. In the case of the Nile, it [has an estuary](http://www.mpaglobal.org/index.php?action=showSpatial&site_code=17740). However, if a river does have a "mouth", the body of water the river empties into is not called "the mouth". Instead, it is just the body of water containing the mouth.

The other end of the river is called its [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_source) or headwaters.

The entire area drained by the river is its [watershed, or drainage basin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drainage_basin).

Answer (score 3):

How about:

> The Mediterranean is the Nile's *[debouchment](http://www.wordnik.com/words/debouchment)*?

Other options along the lines of *affluents* would be to call the Mediterranean the Nile's, egress, exhaust, discharge, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The most common term for this is simply the lake or river’s ***outlet***.  However, that does not say that is the end-point for that body of water.

For that, you may prefer ***endorheic basin***, which per Wikipedia is:

> An **endorheic basin**  (from the Ancient Greek: *ἔνδον, éndon,* “within” and *ῥεῖν, rheîn,* “to flow”), also called a **terminal** or **closed basin**, is a closed drainage basin that retains water and allows no outflow to other external bodies of water, such as rivers or oceans, but converges instead into lakes or swamps, permanent or seasonal, that equilibrate through evaporation.

If so, you may wish to use the simpler *terminal basin* or *closed basin*, so people do not have to look up the fancy Greek term.

For example, although many rivers flow into Lake Tahoe, it has a unique outlet: the Truckee River, which flows into Pyramid Lake where it dead-ends. There is no outlet. Pyramid Lake is the terminal basin for the Truckee River, and ultimately also for Lake Tahoe whose outlet it is.

Answer (score 1):

A term that is commonly used to describe a river system that flows into an ocean, sea, lake or reservoir, is the *mouth* of the river.  In the case of the Nile, it is referred to as a [delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/River_delta).

Comment: The mouth of the river refers to the place where the rivers flows into another body of water. I'm looking for a way a name use for this body of water in relation to the river.

Comment: Not sure if it has a name, unless there's a geological name for it.  I'll do some research.

Comment: @Shawn - The closest I have been able to find is an [estuary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estuary), which is a partly enclosed coastal body of water with one or more rivers or streams flowing into it, and with a free connection to the open sea.  I don't think it is the answer you are looking for though.

Comment: no it is not, thanks a lot anyways for looking into this!

Comment: @Shawn - no problem!  Hope you find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A tributary or Affluent flows to the *Parent River* or *Stem* also called *Trunk* (in reference with hydrology).

An Estuary is a partly enclosed coastal body of water with one or more streams flowing into it. An estuary has a free connection to open sea.