# Openings at the shores where rivers enter

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What do we call those points on the sea shores where rivers join the sea?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42835/what-do-you-call-the-body-of-water-into-which-a-river-flows/77461#77461

Comment: ...in particular, my answer there contains the answer to this question, as well as several other river-related geographic terms that you might find helpful (as do some of the other answers there).

Answer (score 9):

A river joins the sea at its *mouth*. That emphasizes the river, though, not the shoreline.

There are fancier words like *estuary*, *firth*, *inlet*, and the like, which perhaps better draw attention to what happens to the strand at that point, but *mouth of the river* is the most common.

Comment: My vote goes to estuary.

Comment: There are lots of words for such things, depending on which points are salient, and how one determines them. From the ocean, you could call it a landing or just a river. From the land, you might get a delta, or a swamp, or an estuary, or a bay, or a waterfall, or just about anything. There isn't a single word for every possible way of categorizing nature; there can't be.

Comment: @JohnLawler Are you being punny with *salient*? :)

Comment: No, but it does illustrate how one can find metaphors when one is looking for them, doesn't it? _Salience_ is semantics jargon for importance to a concept, like _in a barroom fight, size and speed are salient variables, while eye color and nose size are not_.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, John, I know. I also know where it comes from. I was referring the kind of *sal-* one takes *cum grano salis*.

Comment: Yeah, but _salis_ and _salientis_ are from different roots.

Comment: It depends. San Francisco Bay, New York Harbor, Nile Delta, Thames Estuary, Milford Sound ...

Comment: And, if we're to believe _Top Gear_, the Straits of Gibraltar.