# A word to describe something of two origin/source

Tags: verbs

I'm looking for a word to describe something of two origin/source . Like a river of two origin points.

Comment: Related SE: [Place where two rivers meet](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25545/what-is-a-suitable-word-to-describe-a-place-where-two-rivers-meet)

Comment: I meant a word for a river having two origin points / sources

& Thank you for responding

Comment: A river is part of natural drainage of an area and therefore it has many points of origin. If you mean a river formed by joining two rivers, then see the link posted earlier.

Comment: In another context, "hybrid" may fit.

Comment: Why the verbs tag? An adjective is being requested, yes?

Comment: _Bicipital_ has secondary meanings 'having two heads' or 'having two points of origin', but is not usually used except to describe muscles.

Answer (score 0):

If your viewpoint is looking back towards the sources, it is **bifurcated**, meaning it splits.

If you just want the union of two sets of discrete things, then **commingled**

> to join or mix together

"Commingle." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 2 Apr. 2016.

If you want the state of being composed of two things, it is **conjoint**.

> Combining all or both people or things involved

Oxford dictionaries:http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/conjoint

If the two sources mix, like paint, then **blended** would work. Blended is also used for abstractions like theories or ideas.

> to mix (things) thoroughly and usually with good results
>    to exist together as a combination

"Blend." Merriam-Webster.com. Merriam-Webster, n.d. Web. 2 Apr. 2016.